# why divide 65536 twice during conversion back in binary scaling

Tags: binary, scaling

my understand of binary scaling is that you can represent a floating point value with integer value, so to represent a float 1.2 in short (2 bytes integer), simply 1.2*power(2,16), gives 78643, convert it back would simply divide power(2,16). 
according to link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling, the following:

```
For instance, to represent 1.2 and 5.6 as B16 one multiplies them by 216, giving 78643 and 367001.

Multiplying these together gives

28862059643
To convert it back to B16, divide it by 216.

This gives 440400B16, which when converted back to a floating point number (by dividing again by 216, but holding the result as floating point) gives 6.71999. The correct floating point result is 6.72.
```

What I don't understand is why do we need to divide 65536 (power(2,16) twice when convert back to B16.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let x = 1.2, y = 5.6
Now let x1 = x * 2^16, y1 = y * 2^16
Let z1 = x1 * y1
= (x * 2^16) * (y * 2^16)
= (x * y) * 2^16 * 2^16
```

When the values are multiplied, each one brings a 2^16 with it.  Then you need to remove one of them to return it to B16, and another to return to floating point.

This isn't the case for addition, because (x * 2^16) + (y * 2^16) = (x + y) * 2^16.  Division would be a bad idea, because the 2^16 factors would cancel out, giving you a floating point value stored as an integer.

Comment: thanks Btherl, this sounds about right, though I am thinking, if I have binary scaling value, how do i know that how many multiplications have occured with this value, so in order to convert back to the corresponding floating point value, how do i know how many division I need to do?